# Is there a C++ equivalent to Java's BigDecimal?

Tags: c++, bigdecimal

I'm looking for a C++ class that can do decimal floating point arithmetic. Looking through http://speleotrove.com/decimal/ there are links to all sorts of classes that people have written and not maintained. Digging through the decNumber++ stuff led me to some emails showing that GCC will eventually support this functionality. (Formally known as ISO/IEC TR 24733)

I'm looking for something I can use as a drop-in replacement for float or double, something that other people are using in their own projects. Hopefully open source.

Thanks!

EDIT: I should point out that I'm trying to use this to represent prices. So I need EXACT decimals, not HUGE decimals.

Comment: gmplib maybe? http://gmplib.org/

Comment: you shouldn't use doubles or floats for prices...

Comment: JH I know this, that's why I'm looking for something like BigDecimal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There exists a huge library called [GMP (GNU multiple precision library)](http://gmplib.org/) which supports this and also has C++ bindings, though to be honest the C++ interface is a bit wonky and outdated.

An example from the documentation, the following creates a float called `f` with at least 500 bits of precision:

```
mpf_class f(1.5, 500);
```

Comment: Similar to BigDecimal mpf_class takes a string constructor. The version of gmpxx that ships with Ubuntu 10.4 uses partial template specialization, so it might be a stretch to call it outdated. I think I can get this to do my bidding. Congratulations, you get a cookie, erhm checkmark.

Comment: @poindexter: what I meant with “outdated” is primarily the naming: come on, what kind of class name is “mpf_class”?! They should have called it `gmp::big_float` or something like that.

Comment: I think that's an uphill battle with GNU naming conventions. :)

Answer (score 9):

Take your pick.  There are a bunch of them out there. For instance, you can consult the [list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software).

Comment: libraries section has been removed.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a bit old, but for other people that have the same need : Boost.multiprecision is probably what you're looking for.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/cpp_dec_float.html

It's an arbitrary precision library that can handle 10-based decimals.

Comment: I'd like to warn you against `cpp_dec_float`, 'cause I got a bad experience when tryed to use it.

When I tryed to divide `59999996874999999999999999831` on `31250000` `cpp_dec_float` gave me `0.00000003199...99946064282` (many 9's in the middle) instead of correct `0.000000032`.

When I had changed default locale with `std::locale::globat()` call, conversion to string totally failed 'cause it relies on behaviour of "classic" locale but do not force it.

Don't use.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do operations with HUGE decimal values I would suggest you to use http://gmplib.org/ library. I've used it a lot with C and C++.

Answer (score 3):

Use GMP and store everything as cents. If you know that you won't pass 2^32 cents (42.949673 million dollars) use a 32 bit unsigned int (or use a 64 bit unsigned int) and keep it simple.

Comment: JH, this isn't a good idea. Skim down to the section "Financial Computing" for some examples of how this can fail. http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/91float/

Comment: Its probably a bad idea if u need those specific calculations and don't understand what you are doing, otherwise to represent "prices" floats/doubles seem overrated and incorrect.

Comment: +1: Actually this answer makes more sense to me than most others, which suggest GMP or MAPM. Those arbitrary precision libraries use base 2, which means a value such as `0.1` can never be represented exactly, whatever precision you may set. Storing everything as cents, in other words multiplying everything by 100 and using `int64_t` seems like a perfectly acceptable solution to me. At least all additions will be exact.

Comment: Correction to my last comment: MAPM does use decimal digits internally, so it will be able to represent `0.1` exactly.

Comment: The link @poindexter provided seems to have disappeared, but [it's still available via the WayBack Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20110228024114/http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/91float/)

Comment: When I worked in quantitative trading we multiplied all stock prices by a large power of 10 and stored them as 32 bit integers. Worked fine - and very fast - until someone used the reciprocal of the correct USD/JPY exchange rate and all stock prices became about 10,000 too large, overflowing the integer type. This was caught by the trading engine and fixed relatively quickly. The morale of the story: you can use this method, but be careful about overflows.

Answer (score 3):

I may be too late for this but would 128bit decimals work?
These have been accepted into C++ and at least gcc has them since gcc-4.5 (we're starting 4.9 now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <decimal/decimal>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  {
    std::decimal::decimal32 dn(.3), dn2(.099), dn3(1000), dn4(201);
    dn-=dn2;
    dn*=dn3;
    cout << "decimal32 = "  << (dn==dn4) << " : " << decimal32_to_double(dn) << endl;
  }

  {
    std::decimal::decimal64 dn(.3), dn2(.099), dn3(1000), dn4(201);
    dn-=dn2;
    dn*=dn3;
    cout << "decimal64 = "  << (dn==dn4) << " : " << decimal64_to_double(dn) << endl;
  }

  {
    std::decimal::decimal128 dn(.3), dn2(.099), dn3(1000), dn4(201);
    dn-=dn2;
    dn*=dn3;
    cout << "decimal128 = " << (dn==dn4) << " : " << decimal128_to_double(dn) << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Note there is decimal32 equal in size to float, decimal64 equal in size to most double.  So decimal128 is pretty big.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal128_floating-point_format): Decimal128 supports 34 decimal digits of significand and an exponent range of −6143 to +6144, i.e. ±0.000000000000000000000000000000000×10−6143 to ±9.999999999999999999999999999999999×106144. (Equivalently, ±0000000000000000000000000000000000×10−6176 to ±9999999999999999999999999999999999×106111.)

The mpfr library is arbitrary precision binary floating point - not arbitrary precision decimal.  There is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of BCMath PHP to C++. There are two versions, one for Qt and the other for use only STL.

Source: https://github.com/DesarrollosCuado/BCMath-for-Cpp

```
BCMath::bcscale(4); //Num Decimals
BCMath test("-5978");

test^=30; //Pow, only integers. Not work decimals.
std::cout<<"Result BigDecimal 1: "<<test.toString().c_str()<<std::endl;

test-=1.23; //sub
std::cout<<"Result BigDecimal 2: "<<test.toString().c_str()<<std::endl;

test*=1.23; //mul
std::cout<<"Result BigDecimal 3: "<<test.toString().c_str()<<std::endl;

test*=-1.23; //mul
std::cout<<"Result BigDecimal 4: "<<test.toString().c_str()<<std::endl;

BCMath::bcscale(70); //Num Decimals

BCMath randNum("-5943534512345234545.8998928392839247844353457");
BCMath pi("3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862");

BCMath result1 = randNum + pi;
BCMath result2 = randNum - pi;
BCMath result3 = randNum * pi;
BCMath result4 = randNum / pi;

std::cout<<"Result Super Precision 1: "<<result1.toString().c_str()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Result Super Precision 2: "<<result2.toString().c_str()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Result Super Precision 3: "<<result3.toString().c_str()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Result Super Precision 4: "<<result4.toString().c_str()<<std::endl;

//Other example
BCMath::bcscale(4); //Num Decimals
std::cout<<"Other 1: "<<BCMath::bcmul("1000000.0134", "8.0234").c_str()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Other 2: "<<BCMath::bcadd("1000000.0134", "8.0234").c_str()<<std::endl;

std::cout<<"Compare 1:  "<<BCMath::bccomp("1", "2")<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Compare 2:  "<<BCMath::bccomp("1.00001", "1", 3)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Compare 3:  "<<BCMath::bccomp("1.00001", "1", 5)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Compare 4:  "<<(BCMath("1")< BCMath("2"))<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Compare 5:  "<<(BCMath("1")<=BCMath("2"))<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Compare 6:  "<<(BCMath("1")> BCMath("2"))<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Compare 7:  "<<(BCMath("1")>=BCMath("2"))<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Compare 8:  "<<(BCMath("2")< BCMath("2"))<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Compare 9:  "<<(BCMath("2")<=BCMath("2"))<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Compare 10: "<<(BCMath("2")> BCMath("2"))<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Compare 11: "<<(BCMath("2")>=BCMath("2"))<<std::endl;

std::cout<<"Round 1: "<<BCMath::bcround("123.01254").c_str()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Round 2: "<<BCMath::bcround("-123.01254", 3).c_str()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Round 3: "<<BCMath::bcround("123.01254", 2).c_str()<<std::endl;
pi.round(3);
std::cout<<"Round 4: "<<pi.toString().c_str()<<std::endl;

BCMath part1("-.123");
BCMath part2(".123");
BCMath part3("123");
std::cout<<"Int part 1: "<<part1.getIntPart().c_str()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Dec part 1: "<<part1.getDecPart().c_str()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Int part 2: "<<part2.getIntPart().c_str()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Dec part 2: "<<part2.getDecPart().c_str()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Int part 3: "<<part3.getIntPart().c_str()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Dec part 3: "<<part3.getDecPart().c_str()<<std::endl;
```

Result:

```
Result BigDecimal 1:  198005530669253749533290222782634796336450786581284861381777714804795900171726938603997395193921984842256586113024
Result BigDecimal 2:  198005530669253749533290222782634796336450786581284861381777714804795900171726938603997395193921984842256586113022.7700
Result BigDecimal 3:  243546802723182111925946974022640799493834467494980379499586589209898957211224134482916796088524041355975600919018.0071
Result BigDecimal 4:  -299562567349513997668914778047848183377416395018825866784491504728175717369805685413987659188884570867849989130392.1487

Result Super Precision 1:  -5943534512345234542.7583001856941315459727023167204971158028306006248941790250554076921835
Result Super Precision 2:  -5943534512345234549.0414854928737180228979890832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164
Result Super Precision 3:  -18672164360341183116.9114783895073349180904753962992796943871920962352436079118338887287186
Result Super Precision 4:  -1891885794154043400.2804849527556211973567525043250278948318788149660700494315139982452600

Other 1:  8023400.1075
Other 2:  1000008.0368

Compare 1:   -1
Compare 2:   0
Compare 3:   1
Compare 4:   true
Compare 5:   true
Compare 6:   false
Compare 7:   false
Compare 8:   false
Compare 9:   true
Compare 10:  false
Compare 11:  true

Round 1:  123.0125
Round 2:  -123.013
Round 3:  123.01
Round 4:  3.142

Int part 1:  -0
Dec part 1:  123
Int part 2:  0
Dec part 2:  123
Int part 3:  123
Dec part 3:  0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the next cpp implementation of BigDecimal:

https://github.com/Sam-bit/BigDecimal-CPP

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Probably "MAPM, A Portable Arbitrary Precision Math Library in C" is what you are looking for. It also includes C++ Wrappers:

http://www.tc.umn.edu/~ringx004/mapm-main.html

Comment: FAIL: "Note that the default MAPM library is NOT thread safe. MAPM internal data structures could get corrupted if multiple MAPM functions are active at the same time. The user should guarantee that only one thread is performing MAPM functions. This can usually be achieved by a call to the operating system to obtain a 'semaphore' or 'critical code section' so the operating system will guarantee that only one MAPM thread will be active at a time. "