# New Float number

Tags: c++

i want to make a new float type with a size of 128-bit , the exponent would have 4-bytes(32-bit) and the fraction would have 12-bytes(96-bit), how i can make this type in c++, where i will be able to do input, output ,+,-,*,/  operations.

[I am thinking of c++ class but i can't figure how i will mange up between exponent and fraction with the specified length]

I have tried "bitset" std class, but it has a huge size in comparison with what i need for example "std::bitset<16> foo;" give a size of 8-bytes.

Any Suggestions !

Comment: new char[16], and you have a bitfield of length 128 bits.

Comment: _'"std::bitset<16> foo;" give a size of 8-bytes.'_ Did you check for size of a pointer?? Show some code please!

Comment: Might interess you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798777/is-there-a-c-equivalent-to-javas-bigdecimal

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bitset<32> expo;
   bitset<96> frac;
   
   cout << sizeof(expo) << endl;
   cout << sizeof(frac);
   
   return 0;
}

Comment: i am expecting 4 from the first print statement and 12 from the other but what i get is 8 and 16 ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build your own data type and implement all the operations you want to do with it. This is exactly how a compiler emulates a 64 bit dataset when the architecture supports only 32 bit data native.

So a class/struct with two members is the right starting point. You have to implement the basic operations now: +,-,*,/. Add and sub are easy, you need to pay more attention to * and /. What I can tell you is that usually compiles implement these using repeated add and sub operations.

Comment: thank you, can you help me with a paper or a website pages that talks about this,, i have searched a lot with finding an appropriate one

Comment: @user3038489:  Search for "IEEE floating point format" for some examples of different floating point formats.